# Can I use lamba experssion to obtain an ejb dynamically through strategy pattern with CDI?

Tags: java, lambda, cdi, ejb-3.1, strategy-pattern

I know I can inject as an instance all the beans that match the interface and then choose between them programmatically :

```
@Inject @Any Instance<PaymentProcessor> paymentProcessorSource;
```

That means I have to put the selecting logic into the client.

Can I, as an alternative, cache the value of the ejb using lexical scoping with lambda expression? Will the container be able to correctly manage the lifecycle of the ejb in that case or is this practice to avoid?

For example, having PaymentProcessorImpl1 e PaymentProcessorImpl2 as two strategies of PaymentProcessor, something like that:

```
public class PaymentProcessorProducer {

@Inject
private PaymentProcessorImpl1 paymentProcessorImpl1;

@Inject
private PaymentProcessorImpl2 paymentProcessorImpl2;

@Produces
private Function<String, PaymentProcessor> produce() {

    return (strategyValue) -> {

        if ("strategy1".equals(strategyValue)) {

            return paymentProcessorImpl1;

        } else if ("strategy2".equals(strategyValue)) {

            return paymentProcessorImpl2;

        } else {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Tipo non gestito: " 
                    + strategyValue);
        }

    };

}
```

}

and then into the client to something like that:

```
@Inject
Function<String, PaymentProcessor> paymentProcessor;
```

...

```
paymentProcessor.apply("strategy1")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I, as an alternative, cache the value of the ejb using lexical scoping with lambda expression?

Theoretically, you could do this. Whether it works is easy to try on our own.

> Will the container be able to correctly manage the lifecycle of the ejb in that case or is this practice to avoid?

What exactly is an EJB here? The implementation of `PaymentProcessor`? Note that EJB beans are different from CDI beans. As in CDI container does not control lifecycle of EJB beans, it "only provides a wrapper for you to use them as if they were CDI beans".

That being said, the lifecycle is still the same - in your case the producer is creating `@Dependent` bean meaning every time you inject `Function<String, PaymentProcessor>`, the producer will be invoked.

What poses certain problem is that you create an assumption on two or more context being active at any given time. The moment you decide to actually `apply()` the function, the scope within which your implementation(s) exist may or may not be active. If they are both `ApplicationScoped` for instance, you should be alright. If, however, they are `SessionScoped` and you happen to timeout/invalidate session before applying function, then you get into a very weird state.

**This is probably why I would rather avoid this approach** and go with qualifiers. Or you can introduce a new bean which has both strategies in it and have a method with an argument which decides which strategy to use.